# Requirement for creating WebSphere MQ FTE agents in Windows

Tags: client, ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

I am designing a new file transfer infrastructure using WebSphere MQ v7.5 FTE product and like to know for creating an FTE agent in a Windows box, what is the basic minimum requirement? Does it require the MQ v7.5 server edition installed or will it work with the MQ v7.5 client libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least one WMQ queue manager to act as the queuing hub for all the agents.  The regular FTE agents can be client-based.  Typically, these are placed local to the file endpoints and access the underlying filesystem directly.  For most agents a client connection to a central queue manager works great.  The exception is a node where the transfer volume is very high, in which case it might warrant having a local queue manager.

The exception is the "Protocol Bridge" agents which are the ones that talk to remote FTP, SFTP and FTPS servers.  These must reside on the same host as the queue manager.

Short answer: on your Windows box a client agent is the minimal requirement.  Just point its configuration to a queue manager somewhere on the network.

Comment: Thanks! I am still confused on this. Is that the WebSphere MQ FTE v7.0.4 client edition you have mentioned? I have downloaded WebSphere MQ v7.5 client and could not find fte*.cmd in the bin directory.

Comment: Yes.  The WMQ Client (SupportPac MQC75) and the FTE Client Agent are two different things.  I forget what the name for the FTE Client Agent is now in Passport Advantage but that's where you go to get it and you'll need an entitlement for it.  Entitlements for Server and Client versions of FTE are different part numbers and different code.